# Make labels (X and Y value) appear when hovering over a bar chart

Tags: python, label, bar-chart

My main purpose is to display the value of **x** and **y** while hovering over a specific section on the bar chart which is composed of 4 parts, in order to distinguish the exact amount of error for each variable[B183_0 ... ] in the bar.

Exple: while hovering on A01, B185_0 this value will appear ===> (A01,1000)

[image]

Comment: This  article  contains  the  response : https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/